Openpyxl insert_rows; Mismatch of content and format
I have an Excel file with a worksheet where I want to insert a new row in 6th row (see image 1).
Wanted
If I directly open Excel app and right-click on the 6th row and select “insert”, it will insert a new row which matches the format and content of the previous 6th row (see image 2).
Code and Issue
worksheet.insert_rows(idx=6, amount=1)

However, if I use the above code to insert a new row, the content below the 6th row will be pan to the next row, but the format remains unchanged (see image 3).
For example, I have a merged cell in 9th row. I hope that its format and content will be synchronously pan to the 10th row after insertion. But after I run the code, the content was pan to 10th row, but the merged cell format still remains at 9th row.
Image 1 (before): The original sheet:

Image 2 (after manual edit): The sheet with matched format and content:

Image 3 (after code): The sheet with mismatched format and content:

How can I modify my code to meet my need?

Search and research first (e.g. for [openpyxl] insert), found: Insert row + shifting cells in openpyxl. Does it preserve the format and layout with worksheet.move_range("6:255", rows=1)?

Many of these functions are provided by the Excel Application, if you want to use them, use a module that works with Excel. With Openpyxl you will usually need to copy/move styling when moving data, cell by cell, though there are functions provided to do some of this like that referenced in the comment by @hc_dev. Openpyxl does make this Note ; Openpyxl does not manage dependencies, such as formulae, tables, charts, etc., when rows or columns are inserted or deleted...

A similar question was asked recently which may also be useful to you.

@hc_dev It worked! I really appreciate it for your help and your edition to make my question more explicit.

@moken It does help! It's really kind of you to help me, thanks a lot.

Happy to hear this; then I would close the question as duplicate.  @moken, if you also vote to close as 'Duplicate' for your similar question, we have the formatting and styles aspect covered and linked as well.
